Text overflow issue in table
I am trying to display list in Table. But  text overflow issue raised.
How to fix this issue with css? Kindly guide me.


.pkgtable {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.pkgtable th,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pkgtable ul {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: square;
}

.pkgtable li {
  margin-left: -12px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}





Please share minimal runnable code snippet.

ever considered using the native css flex-box property?
It does wonders with minimal adjustments.
here's my favorite documentation

Add word-wrap and overflow properties to the table cells to handle long text:
.pkgtable {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.pkgtable th, .pkgtable td {
    vertical-align: top;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.pkgtable ul {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: square;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.pkgtable li {
    margin-left: -12px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

Note:- if you will get any further issues change the above css as per your scenario, mainly you have to play with overflow and word-wrap properties.

Here is a working example of CSS that fixes the problem. The key fix is adding "width: 100%" to the ".pkgtable li" element. This ensures that the list items stay contained within their table cell and prevents any overflow.
.pkgtable {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.pkgtable th,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pkgtable ul {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: square;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.pkgtable li {
  margin-left: -12px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

On this image you can see the final result:

